# Apache Ignite with 40 Nodes

Tags: ignite

In our product we have 40 nodes spread across different geography. Each node data should be replicated across all the nodes. At any given time each node should have same data.
How can we use the Apache Ignite for the use case which I have explained ?

For the 40 nodes in Distributed cluster and data spread across different geography locations. Is the Apache Ignite is faster than Redis cluster for Reads and Writes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the data to every node using a [replicated cache](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/configuration-overview). It's possible (though unusual) to do this for all your tables.

However, distributing a cluster across multiple regions is not recommended.